# V-if And V-else aren't working how I want it to. i want to hide one section when the other section is true

Tags: vue.js

I want to hide one section when the other section is true, but I'm not sure if I'm using v-if and v-else in the right way. I tried rearranging the divs with the v-if but no combination I tried works for hiding the div in the way I want.

```
<template>
```

```
    <section id="whiteClawVideo" class="videoWrapper d-block w-100">
       <div class="video-container fluid">
        <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JORN2hkXLyM?autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       </div>
      </section>


 
 <form @submit.prevent="SearchMovies()" class="search-box">
   <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for? " v-model="search" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
 
 

 <div class="movies-list"  v-if="search.value !=''" >
   <div class="movie" v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.imdbID">
     <router-link :to="'/movie/'+movie.imdbID" class="movie-link">
         <img :src="movie.Poster" alt="Movie Poster" />
           <div class="type">{{ movie.Type }}</div>
            <div class="detail">
              <p class="year">{{movie.Year}}</p>
              <h3>{{ movie.Title }}</h3>
              <p>{{movie.imdbID}}</p>
            </div>
     </router-link>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div  class="container" v-else>
   <MovieSection />
   <SecondMovieSection />
 </div>
```

Comment: the v-else doesn't hide.

Comment: That Worked !! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your v-if to just `search !== ''` since that's your model

Comment: @MSingh17 ...and read the bit about the two component declaration paradigms in the vue 3 docs.  static X=Ref() and X.value are for *within* the the functional component declaration